# Passing results of mysql option tag in my form to php not working

Tags: php, mysql, html

I can retrieve the value from all my other fields but this one:

Here is my form code:

```
    <label class="description" >Product Name</label>
    <select name="FullName" id="FullName" > 
         <option "Choose a Product">Choose a category</option>
         <?php
         $sql = "Select FullName from tblProduct";
             if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
             { 
                 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                 { 
                     echo "<option value='".$row['FullName']."'>".$row['FullName']."</option>                                                                                           
                 }
     }
         ?>
    </select>
```

It works perfectly.

Here is my php. Since I can get at all my other form values, it must be in this code:

```
$FullName = $_Post['FullName'];
echo $FullName;
```

This is always empty despite being able to select it in the form.

I'm sure it's something silly, but my eyes are going buggy. Oh and I do plan on escaping my vars but I want to get it working first.

Answer (score 2):

```
$FullName = $_Post['FullName']; 
             ^   ^
```

There you go. Variables in PHP are case-sensitive. That includes super-global variables like `$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_COOKIE` etc. Changing `$_Post` to `$_POST` should fix the issue. Turning on [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) would have made it easier to find this issue.

Answer (score 0):

One very simple mistake:

Change from this

```
$FullName = $_Post['FullName'];
```

To this:

```
$FullName = $_POST['FullName'];
```

Comment: I knew it was silly. All my others are in upper case. Sometimes you can stare at something for hours and not see it. Thank you!

Comment: @user2900988 mark this as your answer if it solved your problem. Glad I could help. And yes I know all of about it. I programmed a lot of PHP before I became a front end developer.